# When using Bukkit API how to access all commands in a server?

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, minecraft, bukkit

How would you access all the commands available in a servers plugin folder?

probably by accessing each plugins individual plugin.yml and getting their commands. But I just want to know how one would go about this. If there's a different way and I'm over thinking this.

Answer (score 2):

You could loop through all of the `HelpTopic`s, and then put their names in a list:

```
// create the List to store command names into
List<String> commandNames = new ArrayList<String>();  

// loop through all of the helpTopics, a list of all commands displayed 
// in /help (therefore all of the commands)
for(HelpTopic cmd : plugin.getServer().getHelpMap().getHelpTopics()){
    commandNames.add(cmd.getName());//add the name of the command to the Array
}
```

You most likely will want to wait until to after all other plugins are enabled before doing this.

Answer (score -2):

You can work with [`PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/event/player/PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent.html) and [`ServerCommandEvent`](http://jd.bukkit.org/rb/apidocs/org/bukkit/event/server/ServerCommandEvent.html).

```
// PlayerCommandPreprocessEvent
if (event.getMessage().toLowerCase().startsWith("/help")) {
    // Player issued: /help
}
// ServerCommandEvent
if (event.getCommand().toLowerCase().startsWith("help")) {
    // Console issued: help 
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question - The question is about how to get all of the commands available, Not how to tell when the command `/help` is run

Comment: @jojodmo `/help` command was an example. However, user3471511 said: _"If there's a different way and I'm over thinking this."_. Also, **you should not vote down an answer that is not your. Be honest.** Please undo your vote.

Comment: I downvoted it because it **doesn't answer the question**! There is no way to get all of the available commands using what you're doing, it only detects when the player types `/help`, or the console types `help`, it doesn't give OP all of the available commands that are *listed* when a player types /help

Comment: @Jojodmo `/help` command was an example! It has nothing to do with all of the available commands that are listed when a player types `/help`! Also, user3471511 said: _"How would you access all the commands available in a servers plugin folder?"_. **"Access" does not mean "get"**.